# Unable to Encapsulate and also ImplementInterface

Tags: c#, silverlight, encapsulation

I am using C# in Silverlight ( I created a new class folder. However, I do not have the option for incapsulate (i had to type out myself, snippets is another problem) also the resolve and implement option (I am using Visual Studio 2010) Please what am i doing wrong?? Here is a example i am trying to resolve and implement the INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

    private string _FirstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }

    private string _greeting;
    public string Greeting
    {
        get { return _greeting; }
        set { _greeting = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the casing! The private string _FirstName has a captial 'F', but the instance variable referenced right below it has a lower case 'f'. Variable names are case-sensitive

Comment: Yea that still isnt going to solve the issue I tried changing that. When i right click on the declared line it is not giving me the option to resolve or implement for INotifyPropertyChanged also same with encapsulating private string _FirstName;For encapsulating I was reading you have do configure or 'import' in code manager which i did but still not working. I am fairly new to visual studio and silverlight but it is cool so i want to know how to use it. Thanks for all your input to solve this!!

Comment: Oh I see. You are talking about how some IDEs will let you right click to auto-implement a feature. Like add stubs for interface methods. I'm sorry but I don't know how to do that in VS

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code should look like:-

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName"); }
    }

    private string _greeting;
    public string Greeting
    {
        get { return _greeting; }
        set { _greeting = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Greeting");  }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony! that is what i want my code to look like and what it would look like after I revivew and implement interface on the INotifyProperty, which i am unable to right click and auto implmenet. Are you familiar with VS and know why I dont have this option to do this?

Comment: @Jeffrey: If you right mouse on the "INotifyPropertyChanged" do you see a Resolve entry in the menu?

Comment: I dont see the Resolve entry in the menu. I also dont see refactor in the menu?? These are what I am looking for.

Comment: @Jeffrey:  Sounds like your VS2010 install is a little messed up.